# how to use reduce function to get the total number of GitHub repository of a user

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the total number of repositories of a user. This is my code below:

js

```
const url = "https://api.github.com/users/oyerohabib/repos?per_page=50";

const fetchRepos = async () => {
  response = await fetch(url);
  data = await response.json();
  const newData = data.reduce((total, repo) => {
    const { language } = repo;
    if (language) {
      total += language;
    }
    return total;
  }, 0);
  console.log(newData);
};

fetchRepos();
```

This is what i get after trying that `0CSSJavaScriptHTMLJavaScriptHTMLJavaScriptHTMLJavaScriptJavaScriptJavaScriptJavaScriptJavaScriptHTMLJavaScript`

Note: What I expect is 13 which is the total count of the languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `1` everytime you see a language to the `total`

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const data = await response.json();
const newData = data.reduce((total, repo) => {
  const { language } = repo;
  if (language) {
    total += 1;
  }
  return total;
}, 0);
```

This returns `14` and just to be sure I added an array of all the languages if you were to append all the languages to an array:

```
const results = [
  "CSS",
  "JavaScript",
  "HTML",
  "JavaScript",
  "HTML",
  "JavaScript",
  "HTML",
  "JavaScript",
  "JavaScript",
  "JavaScript",
  "JavaScript",
  "JavaScript",
  "HTML",
  "JavaScript",
];
```

### Edit:

Here is how you would get the languages in an array

```
response = await fetch(url);
data = await response.json();
const newData = data.reduce((total, repo) => {
  const { language } = repo;
  if (language) {
    total.push(language)
  }
  return total;
}, []);
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Thanks. I skipped that.

Comment: how were you able to get the languages into a narray.